# Clickable prototype contains SVG instead of image

Tags: adobe-xd

We are developing clickable prototype using Adobe XD. We know that the prototype can be exported as SVG file using the export option. We wanted to know if it is possible to have the clickable prototype which is shared via URL contain SVG instead of a single image. If not directly through XD , does any plugins help in this?

Answer (score 0):

The XD prototype view can't be expressed as plain SVG because it includes animation, interaction, and rendering features that SVG doesn't support. And since XD is tech-stack agnostic, it doesn't try to generate complete production code for you.

There are a number of XD plugins that can export code for several different web frameworks – with varying degrees of fidelity and varying degrees of turnkey production-readiness. You might be interested in plugins like Yotako, Flutter Export, Generate Flutter Code, Fireblade, Component to Vue, or Export as React Component.